# JS/jQuery: Help modifying code to replace 4 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

So I have this code (below) that will replace **one** image. I need this to be modified so it will replace **four separate images**, and is triggered after a button (image) is clicked.

Can someone help me do this, and also make it so it is triggered after clicking a button (image). Thanks x

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function() {

            function callback(imageLoader){


                $('#image').attr('src', imageLoader.nextImage());

            }

            function ImageLoader(images){
                this.images = images;
                this.current = 0;

                this.nextImage = function(){
                    this.current = (this.current+1) % this.images.length;
                    return this.images[this.current];;
                }
            }

            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(['img/wallpaper/2.png', 'img/wallpaper/3.png', 'img/wallpaper/6.png', 'img/wallpaper/10.png']);


            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <img id="image" src="img/wallpaper/1.png">

    </body>
</html>
```

If it helps here is my [Design](http://i.imgur.com/p3bS0TU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here, but it does seem like a complicated way to swap out some images? Maybe something more like this would be easier :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = ['img/wallpaper/2.png', 
                  'img/wallpaper/3.png', 
                  'img/wallpaper/6.png', 
                  'img/wallpaper/10.png'
                 ];

    $('#buttonID').on('click', function() {
        $('.image').attr('src', function(i, src) {
            return images[i];
        }); 
    });
});
```

example HTML:

```
<body>
    <img class="image" src="img/wallpaper/1.png" />
    <img class="image" src="img/wallpaper/4.png" />
    <img class="image" src="img/wallpaper/7.png" />
    <img class="image" src="img/wallpaper/9.png" />
    <input type="button" id="buttonID" value="Change images" />
</body>
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! How would I make this keep going, like when I click "change image" for the second time - it changes to another new set of images? Also, is it possible to have a button that would take me'back', like back to the first set of images? x

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var imageLoader;

            function ImageLoader(images)
            {
                this.images = images;
                this.current = 0;

                this.nextImage = function()
                {
                    this.current = (this.current+1) % this.images.length;
                    return this.images[this.current];
                }
             }

             $(document).ready(function()
             {
                 imageLoader = new ImageLoader(
                 [
                     'img/wallpaper/2.png',
                     'img/wallpaper/3.png',
                     'img/wallpaper/6.png',
                     'img/wallpaper/10.png'
                 ]);

                 $('#change').on('click', function()
                 {
                     $('#image').attr('src', imageLoader.nextImage());
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="image" src="img/wallpaper/1.png">
        <input type="button" id="change" value="Change" />
    </body>
</html>
```